# Python setuptools don't give me permission to execute script

Tags: python, pip, package-managers

I'm running the following from the package dir:

```
sudo ./setup.py develop
# or
sudo python setup.py develop
```

The package contains two executables. `setup.py` places them in `/usr/bin/`, but when I'm trying to run them, it fails with:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/<executable>: Permission denied
```

WTF?

---

**OS**: Archlinux x86_64 runnning inside a Vagrant containter via VirtualBox on Windows 7

Under Ubuntu everything worked correctly.

Comment: It looks like the executable file does not have the executable bits set. You can check this with `ls -l /usr/bin/<executable`. If the first 10 characters do not contain `x`-s, only `-`, `w`, or `r`, you need to run `sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/<executable>` to make it executable.

Comment: No, it is executable, but only `root` can execute this. `chmod +x` doesn't help; `chown` helps, but I think it is insecure. And I don't want to fix **this** executable using `chmod`, `chown` or whatever. I want setuptools and pip to install packages right way, because it's not problem in my package, pip installs all packages so that I can't execute them without root permissions.

Comment: Actually, there is some difference between `ls -l` output on executables installed by pip/setuptools (`-rwxr-x---`), and executables installed by pacman (`-rwxr-xr-x`).

Answer (score 2):

I found [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166948/why-is-my-pip-installed-python-script-not-executable-for-everyone) on https://unix.stackexchange.com.

This helped:

```
sudo umask 002
```